# How to allow external users to fork project in gitlab?

Tags: fork, gitlab, external

External user is not allowed to fork project as create project permission is not allowed for them.
Personal projects limit=0 and it cannot be changed.
How to allow external users to fork project in gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

There is an opened issue (2 years ago) on the GitLab website:

[Issue #15173](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15173)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue has been fixed -- I was able to increase the project level for an external user, and confirmed the user was able to fork to their personal project space.